# AWS : how to archive files from S3 to Glacier using only command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command, line

I can't find a command example for archiving a set of files from a given prefix in  S3 into a given vault in Glacier using ONLY COMMAND LINE, i.e. no Lifecycles, no python+boto. Thanks.

This doc has a lot of examples but none fit my request:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't. As described in the [Amazon's S3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html):

> You cannot specify GLACIER as the storage class at the time that you create an object. You create GLACIER objects by first uploading objects using STANDARD, RRS, or STANDARD_IA as the storage class. Then, you transition these objects to the GLACIER storage class using lifecycle management.

Comment: Thank you @guest . So, what would be Lifecycle JSON setting for "do it right now"? Something like       "Expiration": {"Days": 0} ?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for this:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restore-s3-object-glacier-storage-class/

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/key/file s3://bucketname/key/file --storage-class GLACIER
```

optionally use --recursive instead of a specific file name.

Comment: not sure if that's the case. I get `aws: error: argument --storage-class: Invalid choice,`  when using  `--storage-class=GLACIER --recursive`